# Add Campaign Selector in Adwords Script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I have a bid-to-position script that targets keywords that have a label associated with them.  The label contains the desired position and the script adjusts the keyword's bid in order to reach that position.  Right now the script targets any keyword with the label.  I'm trying to edit the script so it will look for labeled keywords in campaigns that I choose.  I tried adding .withCondition(CampaignName = ' My Campaign Name'") to the labelIterator variable but had no luck.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
/**
*
* Average Position Bidding Tool
*
* This script changes keyword bids so that they target specified positions,
* based on recent performance.
*
* Version: 1.2
* Updated 2015-09-28 to correct for report column name changes
* Updated 2016-02-05 to correct label reading, add extra checks and
* be able to adjust maximum bid increases and decreases separately
* Google AdWords Script maintained on brainlabsdigital.com
*
**/
 
// Options
 
var maxBid = 5.00;
// Bids will not be increased past this maximum.
 
var minBid = 0.10;
// Bids will not be decreased below this minimum.
 
var firstPageMaxBid = 1.00;
// The script avoids reducing a keyword's bid below its first page bid estimate. If you think
// Google's first page bid estimates are too high then use this to overrule them.
 
var dataFile = "AveragePositionData.txt";
// This name is used to create a file in your Google Drive to store today's performance so far,
// for reference the next time the script is run.
 
var useFirstPageBidsOnKeywordsWithNoImpressions = false;
// If this is true, then if a keyword has had no impressions since the last time the script was run
// its bid will be increased to the first page bid estimate (or the firsPageMaxBid if that is smaller).
// If this is false, keywords with no recent impressions will be left alone.
 
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
 
// Advanced Options
  var bidIncreaseProportion = 0.2;
  var bidDecreaseProportion = 0.4;
  var targetPositionTolerance = 0.2;
   
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
    
function main() {
 
  var fieldJoin = ",";
  var lineJoin = "$";
  var idJoin = "#";
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(dataFile);
  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(dataFile,"");
    Logger.log("File '" + dataFile + "' has been created.");
  } else {
    var file = files.next();
    if (files.hasNext()) {
      Logger.log("Error - more than one file named '" + dataFile + "'");
      return;
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var labelIds = [];
   
  var labelIterator = AdWordsApp.labels()
  .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'MY CAMPAIGN NAME' ")
  .withCondition("KeywordsCount > 0")
  .withCondition("LabelName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'Position '")
  .get();
   
  while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
    var label = labelIterator.next();
    if (label.getName().substr(0,"position ".length).toLowerCase() == "position ") {
      labelIds.push(label.getId());
    }
  }
   
  if (labelIds.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("No position labels found.");
    return;
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var keywordData = {
    //UniqueId1: {LastHour: {Impressions: , AveragePosition: }, ThisHour: {Impressions: , AveragePosition: },
    //CpcBid: , FirstPageCpc: , MaxBid, MinBid, FirstPageMaxBid, PositionTarget: , CurrentAveragePosition:,
    //Criteria: }
  }
   
  var ids = [];
  var uniqueIds = [];
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(
    'SELECT Id, Criteria, AdGroupId, AdGroupName, CampaignName, Impressions, AveragePosition, CpcBid, FirstPageCpc, Labels, BiddingStrategyType ' +
    'FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
    'WHERE Status = ENABLED AND AdGroupStatus = ENABLED AND CampaignStatus = ENABLED ' +
    'AND LabelIds CONTAINS_ANY [' + labelIds.join(",") + '] ' +
    'AND AdNetworkType2 = SEARCH ' +
      'AND Device NOT_IN ["HIGH_END_MOBILE"] ' +
        'DURING TODAY'
      );
   
  var rows = report.rows();
   
  while(rows.hasNext()){
    var row = rows.next();
     
    if (row["BiddingStrategyType"] != "cpc") {
      if (row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Enhanced CPC"
      || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Target search page location"
      || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Target Outranking Share"
      || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "None"
      || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "unknown") {
        Logger.log("Warning: keyword " + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] +
                   "' uses '" + row["BiddingStrategyType"] + "' rather than manual CPC. This may overrule keyword bids and interfere with the script working.");
      } else {
        Logger.log("Warning: keyword " + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] +
                   "' uses the bidding strategy '" + row["BiddingStrategyType"] + "' rather than manual CPC. This keyword will be skipped.");
        continue;
      }
    }
     
    var positionTarget = "";
     
    var labels = row["Labels"].toLowerCase().split("; ")
    for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
      if (labels[i].substr(0,"position ".length) == "position ") {
        var positionTarget = parseFloat(labels[i].substr("position ".length-1).replace(/,/g,"."),10);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (positionTarget == "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (integrityCheck(positionTarget) == -1) {
      Logger.log("Invalid position target '" + positionTarget +  "' for keyword '" + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] + "'");
      continue;
    }
     
    ids.push(parseFloat(row['Id'],10));
    var uniqueId = row['AdGroupId'] + idJoin + row['Id'];
    uniqueIds.push(uniqueId);
     
    keywordData[uniqueId] = {};
    keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] = row['Criteria'];
    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour'] = {};
     
    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['Impressions'] = parseFloat(row['Impressions'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'] = parseFloat(row['AveragePosition'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
     
    keywordData[uniqueId]['CpcBid'] = parseFloat(row['CpcBid'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
    keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'] = parseFloat(row['FirstPageCpc'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
        
    setPositionTargets(uniqueId, positionTarget);
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  setBidChange();
  setMinMaxBids();
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var currentHour = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), "HH"), 10);
   
  if (currentHour != 0) {
    var data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var data = data.split(lineJoin);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      data[i] = data[i].split(fieldJoin);
      var uniqueId = data[i][0];
      if(keywordData.hasOwnProperty(uniqueId)){
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour'] = {};
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour']['Impressions'] = parseFloat(data[i][1],10);
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour']['AveragePosition'] = parseFloat(data[i][2],10);
      }
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  findCurrentAveragePosition();
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  try {
    updateKeywords();
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Error updating keywords: " + e);
    Logger.log("Retrying after one minute.");
    Utilities.sleep(60000);
    updateKeywords();
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  var content = resultsString();
   
  file.setContent(content);
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  // Functions
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function integrityCheck(target){
    var n = parseFloat(target, 10);
    if(!isNaN(n) && n >= 1){
      return n;
    }
    else{
      return -1;
    }
     
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function setPositionTargets(uniqueId, target){
    if(target !== -1){
      keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] = Math.max(target-targetPositionTolerance, 1);
      keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'] = target+targetPositionTolerance;
    }
    else{
      keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] = -1;
      keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'] = -1;
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function bidChange(uniqueId){
     
    var newBid = -1;
    if(keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] === -1){
      return newBid;
    }
     
    var cpcBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['CpcBid'];
    var minBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['MinBid'];
    var maxBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['MaxBid'];
     
    if (isNaN(keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'])) {
      Logger.log("Warning: first page CPC estimate is not a number for keyword '" + keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] + "'. This keyword will be skipped");
      return -1;
    }
     
    var firstPageBid = Math.min(keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'], keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageMaxBid'], maxBid);
     
    var currentPosition = keywordData[uniqueId]['CurrentAveragePosition'];
    var higherPositionTarget = keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'];
    var lowerPositionTarget = keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'];
     
    var bidIncrease = keywordData[uniqueId]['BidIncrease'];
    var bidDecrease = keywordData[uniqueId]['BidDecrease'];
     
    if((currentPosition > lowerPositionTarget) && (currentPosition !== 0)){
      var linearBidModel = Math.min(2*bidIncrease,(2*bidIncrease/lowerPositionTarget)*(currentPosition-lowerPositionTarget));
      var newBid = Math.min((cpcBid + linearBidModel), maxBid);
    }
    if((currentPosition < higherPositionTarget) && (currentPosition !== 0)) {
      var linearBidModel = Math.min(2*bidDecrease,((-4)*bidDecrease/higherPositionTarget)*(currentPosition-higherPositionTarget));
      var newBid = Math.max((cpcBid-linearBidModel),minBid);
      if (cpcBid > firstPageBid) {
        var newBid = Math.max(firstPageBid,newBid);
      }
    }
    if((currentPosition === 0) && useFirstPageBidsOnKeywordsWithNoImpressions && (cpcBid < firstPageBid)){
      var newBid = firstPageBid;
    }
     
    if (isNaN(newBid)) {
      Logger.log("Warning: new bid is not a number for keyword '" + keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] + "'. This keyword will be skipped");
      return -1;
    }
     
    return newBid;
     
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function findCurrentAveragePosition(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      if(keywordData[x].hasOwnProperty('LastHour')){
        keywordData[x]['CurrentAveragePosition'] = calculateAveragePosition(keywordData[x]);
      } else {
        keywordData[x]['CurrentAveragePosition'] = keywordData[x]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'];
      }
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function calculateAveragePosition(keywordDataElement){
    var lastHourImpressions = keywordDataElement['LastHour']['Impressions'];
    var lastHourAveragePosition = keywordDataElement['LastHour']['AveragePosition'];
     
    var thisHourImpressions = keywordDataElement['ThisHour']['Impressions'];
    var thisHourAveragePosition = keywordDataElement['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'];
     
    if(thisHourImpressions == lastHourImpressions){
      return 0;
    }
    else{
      var currentPosition = (thisHourImpressions*thisHourAveragePosition-lastHourImpressions*lastHourAveragePosition)/(thisHourImpressions-lastHourImpressions);
      if (currentPosition < 1) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return currentPosition;
      }
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function keywordUniqueId(keyword){
    var id = keyword.getId();
    var idsIndex = ids.indexOf(id);
    if(idsIndex === ids.lastIndexOf(id)){
      return uniqueIds[idsIndex];
    }
    else{
      var adGroupId = keyword.getAdGroup().getId();
      return adGroupId + idJoin + id;
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function setMinMaxBids(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      keywordData[x]['MinBid'] = minBid;
      keywordData[x]['MaxBid'] = maxBid;
      keywordData[x]['FirstPageMaxBid'] = firstPageMaxBid;
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function setBidChange(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      keywordData[x]['BidIncrease'] = keywordData[x]['CpcBid'] * bidIncreaseProportion/2;
      keywordData[x]['BidDecrease'] = keywordData[x]['CpcBid'] * bidDecreaseProportion/2;
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function updateKeywords() {
    var keywordIterator = AdWordsApp.keywords()
    .withIds(uniqueIds.map(function(str){return str.split(idJoin);}))
    .get();
    while(keywordIterator.hasNext()){
      var keyword = keywordIterator.next();
       
      var uniqueId = keywordUniqueId(keyword);
       
      var newBid = bidChange(uniqueId);
       
      if(newBid !== -1){
        keyword.setMaxCpc(newBid);
      }
       
    }
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
  function resultsString(){
     
    var results = [];
    for(var uniqueId in keywordData){
      var resultsRow = [uniqueId, keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['Impressions'], keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition']];
      results.push(resultsRow.join(fieldJoin));
    }
     
    return results.join(lineJoin);
  }
   
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so CampaignName isn't a valid with condition for the label selector. What you need to do instead is have a Campaign Selector in a while look before you come to your Label selector, which then feeds from the campaign iteration. I've done a quick and dirty example below, but of course, you'd have to take a look to see if doing this will require other changes later on (or earlier on) in your code.

```
  var labelIds = [];

  var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
    .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'MY CAMPAIGN NAME' ")
    .get()

  while (campaignIterator.hasNext())
  {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next()
    var labelIterator = campaign.labels()
    .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'MY CAMPAIGN NAME' ")
    .withCondition("KeywordsCount > 0")
    .withCondition("LabelName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'Position '")
    .get();

     while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
       var label = labelIterator.next();
      if (label.getName().substr(0,"position ".length).toLowerCase() == "position ") {
        labelIds.push(label.getId());
      }
      }

     if (labelIds.length == 0) {
     Logger.log("No position labels found.");
        return;
     }
  }

  var labelIterator = AdWordsApp.labels()
```

Comment: Thanks Luke.  I ran a test with it but I still got the error - CampaignName is invalid.  I removed the CampaignName condition from the labelIterator and ran the test again which then gave me the response - No position labels found.  I've looked through the script and don't see anywhere else that needs an edit.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?